# Using the Right Ruby Version With RVM on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, rvm

There is a discrepancy between my ruby version of RVM, and the actual version that my system seems to use.

Discrepancy:

```
max@max-VirtualBox:~/ruby/app$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
max@max-VirtualBox:~/ruby/app$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ i686 ]
```

So I tried,

```
max@max-VirtualBox:~/ruby/app$ rvm --default use 1.9.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

and my `rvm info` lists ruby 1.9.3 as my default ruby version, and rvm has been updated. But my rails app still seems to be in ruby 1.8.7 syntax, as it says in `ruby -v`

How do I make it that my entire system is using the right ruby version?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RVM has not properly integrated into your shell

a) try to reinstall it with `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

b) (OR) try to manually add following lines to the end of your `$HOME/.bashrc` OR `$HOME/.profile` file

```
export rvm_prefix=$HOME
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

You'll have to restart your shell to reload these vars

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your shell since you installed RVM?

Answer (score 0):

RVM should warn you about this - you need to change your terminal emulator preferences: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

Answer (score -1):

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function` 
Add this to your environment profile (.bashrc or other), and `source` it.